# Necesito imprimir el elemento de un array según un valor introducido

Tags: java, array

Tengo un arreglo en donde tengo declarado los meses del año, lo que necesito es que el usuario me digite un numero y conforme a ese numero yo pueda imprimir el mes que está dentro de mi arreglo.

Ejemplo:

1 = Enero

2 = Febrero

etc.

Comment: Pon el código que hayas probado hasta el momento por lo menos....

Comment: Son tus deberes?

Comment: @IvanIsayenko En realidad, que sean sus deberes o no, no debería influir en la respuesta. Si ha planteado la pregunta bien (escribiendo el código que ha probado, explicando el problema, etc.) significa que ya ha aprendido mucho de lo que le pedía el ejercicio, y que terminará de aprenderlo todo con la respuesta. El problema son las preguntas de "éste es el enunciado, dadme el código".

Comment: @SJuan76 Yo por lo que entiendo es que ni lo ha intentado hacer, ha puesto aquí el anunciado y espera una solución, ojo, podría estar equivocado, no lo descarto.

Comment: @IvanIsayenko No, si estoy de acuerdo que ésta es una mala pregunta y que debería ser cerrada, pero que sean deberes o un ejercicio que se ha buscado por internet no debería ser relevante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes una array con los nombres de los meses?
Por lo que dices tiene pinta a ser esto.

```
    ArrayList<String> meses=new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    meses.add("Enero");
    meses.add("Febrero");
    meses.add("Marzo");
    meses.add("Abril");
    //etc
    System.out.println("Inserte un mes");

    int i = sc.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println(meses.get(i-1));
```

Comment: `System.out.println(meses.get(i - 1));` Pondrá mes 1, no mes 0.

Comment: Tienes razón, que torpe.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me ha servido demasiado aunque lo resolví con un switch,  gracias por el aporte.